# Approximating a function with a sum of decaying exponentials

Tags: summation, exponential-function, approximation

Let's say I have a collection of decaying exponentials of the form
$$
A_i \exp(-x / d_i),
$$
and I want their sum (actually the square of their sum) to approximate a 'peaked' function. For example, consider
$$
A_1 = 1, \quad A_2 = -1, \quad d_1 = 432, \quad d_2 = 166,
$$
over the range of $x \in [0, 1000]$.

This produces a result that looks like:

[image: Exponentials plot]

where the first plot shows the two exponentials and the second is the square of the sum. This is nice, but I'd really like more exponentials and a more 'peaked' function. In the ideal case, I'd have a top-hat function where I could control the centre of the hat.

I've found [this paper](https://amath.colorado.edu/faculty/beylkin/papers/BEY-MON-2005.pdf) that provides methods for complex exponentials, but I want all of mine to be real. Is this something that can be found analytically? If not, are there better methods than just trying a non-linear least-squares fit?

Comment: Are all parameters unknown ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust Yes. In the final application they will be bounded by physical constraints (particularly the $d_i$, which effectively can't be less than 100), but I'm not too bothered about that at this point.

Comment: Then there is nothing better than a non-linear fit, which risks to be numerically unstable for more than a few terms.

Comment: Does the question possibly represent an XY-problem? Is the goal trying to match an experimental distribution? In that case maybe look into a skewed Gaussian or  a Gamma distribution?

Comment: No, it's not an XY problem. I don't want the distribution I showed, I want something with a sharper peak.